# Is it possible to write an applet that connects to Oracle via JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, security, jdbc, applet

I have created a simple applet (`Java 1.7.0_07`), in which I attempt to connect to an Oracle database (`ojdbc6.jar`). The applet works fine in my IDE's applet viewer but does not run correctly from the web.

I am getting security exceptions, so I signed the jar file thinking that would fix it but I am still getting security exceptions, namely:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection$1.run(PhysicalConnection.java:3147)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getSystemProperty(PhysicalConnection.java:3143)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:736)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:519)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ericr.signedApplet.SignedApplet.init(SignedApplet.java:61)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to get things in order and there seems to be conflicting information on how to set this up.

So... Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? If so is there a guide that lets me know what I need to do security-wise in order to get the applet to work correctly when accessed from the web?

Thanks...

Comment: You should read about self signed applets. If applet is signed it does not differ from desktop application. It can access other hosts or filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes down to the `AccessControlException`.  The applet will apparently need to be trusted in order to read the `oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior` property.

OTOH it is generally advisable to restrict access to the DB by putting it behind a web service.  In that case, the applet can simply connect to the web service at the same site, and do what it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

It *is*, or is *supposed* to be possible to connect to an Oracle database, via JDBC, from an applet; see [Chapter 24, "JDBC in Applets", in the *Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference* for Oracle 10g Release 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/applet.htm) for instructions, or [its seeming analogue for Oracle 10g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcthin.htm#CACJHJAE).

Comment: Although I fail to see any scenario in which you would expose the JDBC connection to direct access from code in a browser, as opposed to @AndrewThompson's suggestion to put the DB behind a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to check out a [VJDBC](http://vjdbc.sourceforge.net/) project. It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two environments could be related to the parameters that you're using for your JVM's.  In NetBeans, for my *Apache Tomcat* server, I clicked on and enabled the option "Use Security Manager" and after that, I saw that I was getting the same exact errors that you were getting for my web server.

To find this option, go to the top menu and click Tools > Server.  Then, click on your web server under "Servers" in the left menu.  On the right menu, click the "Platform" tab and then disable "Use Security Manager" and that might resolve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to check permission accessing the oracle folder or add user to oracle group

Comment: Please add this type of response in comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).